# Como centrar hasta 200 caracteres de texto al imprimir en php

Tags: php

Estoy aprendiendo php y necesito modificar la impresión de unos tickets en una aplicación de mi trabajo. He logrado que funcione correctamente pero tengo un problema.

Se ha agregado un campo leyenda2 que es una descripción variable, de 1 hasta 200 caracteres. 
Yo en otra parte del código detecto si existe leyenda o no, y en caso exista la imprimo dentro del ticket.

El tema es que mediante un for each he logrado que la imprima pero queda alineada a la izquierda y la necesidad es que se imprima alineada al centro.

Copio el código relacionado a imprimir :

```
    $lines = explode('|', wordwrap($leyenda2, 40, '|'));
    $x=27; $y=220; $int=40;
    imagettftext ($dest, 18 , 0 , $x , $y , 0 , $vardir.'arial.ttf' , "Fecha: $vfecha" ); $y+=$int;
    imagettftext ($dest, 18 , 0 , $x , $y , 0 , $vardir.'arial.ttf' , "$vpuntos puntos" ); $y+=$int;
    imagettftext ($dest, 18 , 0 , $x , $y , 0 , $vardir.'arial.ttf' , "Socio nro.: $vnrosocio" ); $y+=$int;
    imagettftext ($dest, 18 , 0 , $x , $y , 0 , $vardir.'arial.ttf' , "$vapellido $vnombre" ); $y+=$int;
    imagettftext ($dest, 18 , 0 , $x , $y , 0 , $vardir.'arial.ttf' , "DNI $vdni" );  $y+=$int;
    imagettftext ($dest, 18 , 0 , $x , $y , 0 , $vardir.'arial.ttf' , "Premio: $vpremio" ); $y+=$int;
    imagettftext ($dest, 18 , 0 , $x , $y , 0 , $vardir.'arial.ttf' , "$vdescpremio" ); $y+=$int;

    if ($vcate=="Accesorio2") {
        imagettftext ($dest, 18 , 0 , $x , $y , 0 , $vardir.'arial.ttf' , " " );  $y+=$int;
        imagettftext ($dest, 18 , 0 , $x , $y , 0 , $vardir.'arial.ttf' , " " );  $y+=$int;

        foreach ($lines as $line)
        {
            imagettftext($dest, 18, 0, $x, $y, $font_color, $vardir.'arial.ttf', $line);
            $y += $int;
        }

    }
```

En la variable leyenda2 tengo el texto que necesito formatear.

En la linea : `if ($vcate=="Accesorio2")` defino que si es Accesorio2 imprima la layenda.

Aqui muestro una gráfica con lo que obtengo actualmente, y abajo lo que necesito :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ultima versión del código qu eno funciona, pero calculo está cercano :

```html
<?php
Header("Content-type: image/png");
$im = imagecreate(400,300);
$fondo=imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 110);
$gris=imagecolorallocate ($im, 160, 160,160);
$negro=imagecolorallocate ($im, 0, 0, 0);
$texto="Estosos dsdwsvwes rbbuna rbprueba de impresio Esto esrbbrrbr una prueba de impresiorbrr Esto es una prueba de impresion";
$lines1 = explode('|', wordwrap($texto, 28, '|'));
$y=150;
 foreach ($lines1 as $line1) {
   {
   $line1=trim($line1);
   $line1 = str_pad($line1, 40,"0", STR_PAD_BOTH);
   $bbox = imagettfbbox(18, 0,'arial.ttf', $line1);
   $ancho_max=$bbox[2]-$bbox[0];
   $bbox_fila = imagettfbbox(18, 0, 'arial.ttf', $line1);
   $dx = ($ancho_max - ($bbox_fila[2] - $bbox_fila[0]))/2;
   imagettftext($im, 18, 0, $x + $dx, $y, $negro,'arial.ttf', $line1);
      }  
  }
Imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: Hola Look68, puedes mostrar que resultado estás obteniendo y lo que deseas?

Comment: Ahí edité la pregunta agregando una gráfica !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías usar la función `str_pad` para rellenar cada fila hasta que tenga 40 caracteres:

```
foreach ($lines as $line)
        {
            $line = str_pad($line, 40," ", STR_PAD_BOTH);
            imagettftext($dest, 18, 0, $x, $y, $font_color, $vardir.'arial.ttf', $line);
            $y += $int;
        }
```

Eso insertará espacios a ambos lados hasta completar 40 caracteres.

**Edit:** dado el problema que en muchas tipografías el ancho de las letras no es uniforme, y que el usuario no pueda usar una tipografía monospace, la alternativa es usar **imagettfbbox**.

Generamos, como referencia, un string de 40 "X" que será nuestra caja máxima:

```
$string_referencia=str_pad("X", 40,"X", STR_PAD_BOTH);
```

Medimos su ancho

```
$bbox = imagettfbbox(18, 0, $vardir.'arial.ttf', $string_referencia);
$ancho_max=$bbox[2]-$bbox[0];
```

Luego para cada fila, le añadimos a la posición X el delta necesario para centrar:

```
$bbox_fila = imagettfbbox(18, 0, $vardir.'arial.ttf', $line);
$dx = ($ancho_max - ($bbox_fila[2] - $bbox_fila[0]))/2
imagettftext($dest, 18, 0, $x + $dx, $y, $font_color, $vardir.'arial.ttf', $line);
```

**Edit:** para clarficar, el código quedaría:

```
$string_referencia=str_pad("X", 40,"X", STR_PAD_BOTH);
$bbox = imagettfbbox(18, 0, $vardir.'arial.ttf', $string_referencia);
$ancho_max=$bbox[2]-$bbox[0];

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $bbox_fila = imagettfbbox(18, 0, $vardir.'arial.ttf', $line);
    $dx = ($ancho_max - ($bbox_fila[2] - $bbox_fila[0]))/2
    imagettftext($dest, 18, 0, $x + $dx, $y, $font_color, $vardir.'arial.ttf', $line);
    $y += $int;
    }
```

Comment: Hola disculpa, va bien, pero la tipografía es arial y tengo problemas con el ancho de los caracteres, no funciona bien. Se te ocurre algo para solucionar ? Gracias

Comment: Agregué una salida alternativa pero rebuscada. Avísame si te sirve

Comment: Ahi actualicé el código, por alguna razón que no pude encontrar dejó de funcionar

Comment: $bbox y $ancho_max debieras definirlo fuera del `foreach` y a partir de un string inventado. Asi como lo tienes estás redefiniendo el ancho de referencia en cada loop. Voy a editar mi respuesta para ser más claro